# eval Remote Code From My Server

Tags: php, eval

I am building a site platform similar to Wordpress that allows my users to download a `.zip` file, upload it onto their server, and be good to go.

I know everyone says `eval()` is evil - but the code will not include any user or variable input.

The benefit here is that updates will occur automatically. I can just change the code being grabbed on my server.

My clients using the code will have pretty low traffic sites - so I'm not worried about overloading their server. Most of the heavy lifting will be done by us.

Here's the basic code concept:

```
$code=file_get_contents("http://myserver.com/code.txt");
eval($code);
```

Is this a realistic option? What security holes do I need to worry about?

Comment: The first thing that come in my mind is that the user has full access to your machine when you evalize his code, hence he can just delete your home directory and wrap a red dragon or something like that. The question is: can you trust your own users? if so, fine, else, be careful. That said, as long as they don't have access to database and as long as your directories are properly protected with the correct CHMOD settings, you **should** be **quite** safe, but I won't do that, that's just my opinion though. In a nutshell anyway, eval is not evil because of user's variable inputs.

Comment: I think you have my system backwards. The code posted will be placed on my *clients* servers. Their servers will grab the code off *my* server and eval it.

Comment: Oh okay, then it's your client's issue :P In a nutshell, they agree to get a piece of code that **may be evil**, but as long as they **trust you** that's okay. Just be careful because if someone finds any kind of way to inject you then they will be injected too, which may be dangerous but, as long as they are okay with that and they trust you it's perfectly okay. Be aware, though, that evalizing code makes it quite hard to debug / read, hence please consider that point too. In that context, anyway, it's rather their "issue", not really your :)

Answer (score 0):

It's "realistic" in the sense that it will work, but at the same time it sounds like a sysadmin's nightmare. If you are meaning to have a client download and execute remote code every time a request is made, your clients are at your whim if the master server goes down or is unreachable at any point. It's now a mission-critical service you'll have to keep running forever for as long as your clients need it.

You list automatic updates as a benefit, but is it? In nearly every software platform, the features users depend on can change over time; function signatures can change, or functionality may be dropped entirely in favour of a more refined alternative. Since it sounds like you're writing some form of framework, can you guarantee that future versions will always be backwards-compatible? Not everyone is using the cutting-edge version of a piece of software in production for a reason -- they want what they are using to be stable. If an upgraded version of your platform rolls out overnight, and it breaks some custom code written by the client (at least one of them will try doing this, even if you don't want them to) or even, old, standard functionality that was deprecated but still worked with the previous release, how are they going to roll it back to a version that works?

It just sounds like something that will eventually incur a ton of technical debt.